# Wrong dates marked on Tapku calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4, tapku

I am using Tapku calendar control in my app. So far, I was able to use it correctly. The problem occurred when I tried to mark dates on calendar.
I have following dates that need to be marked on calendar - Month is March , dates are 26, 27, 28, 30.

Now as the calendar starts display from 26-Feb to 4th April, out of which 24th feb to 28th Feb are the dates for last month, now when it comes to mark dates on calendar, the dates 26, 27, 28 are present for Feb as well as March in the calendar control frame. While trying to draw calendar data, 26, 27 , 28 dates of Feb occur first and get marked. Which is wrong. I want to mark dates for march.

I tried to change calendar control's start date and set it to start of March, but the marks were not displayed.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
 NSDate *date = startDate;


int r ;
int i =0;

if([sortedDatesArray count] > 0){  // check if array is not blank

while(YES){


    // int dt = 9;



    NSString *dtStr = [sortedDatesArray objectAtIndex:i];



    r = [dtStr intValue];

    TKDateInformation info = [date dateInformationWithTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    info.day++;



    if(r + 1 == info.day){



        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];  // stores bool for date value

        if(i < [sortedDatesArray count] - 1)
            i++;
    }
    else{
        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    }



    date = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    if([date compare:end]==NSOrderedDescending) break;



}//while



}//if
```

Comment: I FOUND THAT SAME THING HAPPENS WITH TAPKU DEMO AS WELL .. PLEASE HELP. NEED TO DISPLAY RIGHT DATES ...

Comment: What is date formate your storing into the array please

Comment: dataArray has marks for the calendar in the form of 0s and 1s...

Comment: As date 28 appears twice in calendar - one for feb and one for march, there are marks on both the dates :(

Comment: I think you only check the date . you also have to check the month as well i think So

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Harish, Solution to this problem was to check month as well.

Comment: what do you mean with checking month. In my api , i have only my days. And in tapku library, if i dont add like below formate , i cant see my date as marked.

self.CalenderDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            @"2013-09-01 22:00:00 +0000",@"2013-08-09 22:00:00 +0000",@"2013-10-12 00:00:00 +0000", nil];    for example, normally it should show 9 august but i see as 10 agust and also don show the 12 october as well because ,i added the hours like 00:00:00 +0000 ? what can be the problem?